# redux-observable return multiple action types

Tags: redux-observable

I am using redux-observable and this is what I am trying to do.

1. When an actiontype of 'APPLY_SHOPPING_LIST' comes in dispatch 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LIST' and after 5 seconds dispatch 'APPLIED_SHOPPING_LIST'.  This is the code that I have come up with so far

   ```
   const applyingShoppingListSource = action$.ofType('APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS').mapTo({ type: 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS' });

   const applyingShoppingListSourceOther = action$.ofType('APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS').mapTo({ type: 'APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS' }).delay(5000);

   const concatList = applyingShoppingListSource.concat(applyingShoppingListSourceOther);
   ```

   return concatList;

Now the problem is that only 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS' gets fired, the 'APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS' does not get fired to the reducer at all.  Am I missing something here?

Just to add to this, when I used flatMap it worked, given below is the code

```
 return action$.ofType('APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS')
        .flatMap(() => Observable.concat(Observable.of({ type: 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS' }), Observable.of({ type: 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS' });
```

I am confused how this works and the other does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple issues. Since Observables are lazy, your second `action$.ofType('APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS')` for `applyingShoppingListSourceOther` is being concat'd after the first `applyingShoppingListSource`, so it won't be listening for `APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS` until after the first one is has completed, but it will never realistically complete because you're taking *all* actions that match, forever.

Said another way, your code does this:

- Start listening for `APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS` and when received map it to `APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS`
- When that first Observable completes (it never does) start listening for `APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS` again, this time when received map it to `APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS` but wait 5000 ms before emitting it.

You could solve the particular issue of the first not ever completing by using `.take(1)` or `.first()` (same thing), but you usually need to write your epics to not ever stop listening so they respond to actions at any time.

I think what you want is this:

```
const exampleEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('APPLY_SHOPPING_LISTS')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.of({ type: 'APPLYING_SHOPPING_LISTS' })
        .concat(
          Observable.of({ type: 'APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS' })
            .delay(5000)
        )
    );
```

I used `mergeMap` but you may want to use `switchMap` to cancel any previously pending `APPLIED_SHOPPING_LISTS` that haven't emitted yet. Your call.

Comment: thanks for this, and this does work, however just to clarify, what do you mean by the first Observable never completes, do I have to explicitly complete it, I though that first statement .mapTo automatically completes it?

Comment: the stream of actions provided to you by redux-observable represents every possible action your app may dispatch--and since redux apps don't _normally_ terminate, that stream will never complete naturally. So when you say map action X to Y, it will do so until the source aka `action$` completes. Every X received will be mapped to Y, in most apps indefinitely. If you added `.take(1)` it would mean only take the first X seen and map it to Y, then complete.

Comment: I say "most apps" because in some server-side rendering cases you may actually "stop" your stream of actions to signal an end, but I haven't seen this often--I just hate speaking in absolutes.

Comment: btw this isn't a redux-observable thing really, this is Observables--they are a stream zero, 1, or more values over time. So some Observables will never emit anything, some will emit one thing and complete, some will emit many things and never complete, etc. Epics subscribe to a stream of all the actions dispatched in your app. They are "process managers" listening in, throughout the life of your app.